# Block videos from certain users on YouTube

Tags: youtube

YouTube itself does not provide such functionality to block a user from being able to see a certain video.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: See this wiki entry from google http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56113

Comment: I mean videos, not comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way you can do that on YouTube.

Anyhow,

1. You can mark the videos you upload as "Adult", so that sign-in would be required to see the video and YouTube users who have an age below 18 according to the birthday they provided during creation of account will not be able to see the video.
2. You may make your YouTube video uploaded to be available only in certain countries.
3. While uploading the YouTube video, you may mark it as "Private" and share it with up to 10 YouTube users who are your 'Friends' on YouTube.
4. Do not use your real name in your YouTube Profile/Channel and do not let your friends/family/the particular person know your name on YouTube (if that makes any sense in your case)